# Can I use join with across from dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I do not want to use all variables in data frame. I was thinking of something like this, but it comes up with an error.

```
df1 %>% 
full_join(df2, by = 'DATE':'Vz').
```

Both data frame contain the same variables from DATE to Vz. I am interested in bringing the non-zero values of df2 to df1.

Thank you.

Comment: To join by all columns you don't need to specify them.

Comment: Yes, I need it. Otherwise, the names are duplicated. var1.x   var1.y

Answer (score 1):

You can join by multiple columns with dplyr. Let me know if this answers your question:

```r
library(dplyr)

full_join(df1, df2, 
  by=colnames(d1)[which(colnames(df1)=="DATE"):which(colnames(df1)=="Vz")])
```

Comment: I have 100 variables. The idea is avoid that yi = yi...

Comment: Do my edits work?

Comment: This is more like an append than what I'm looking for because this method duplicate the rows.

Comment: Have you tried left_join with my solution, or joining the version of df2 that is filtered for nonzero values? Alternatively, you can use my solution then do distinct() afterwards to get rid of duplicated rows.